# how to run mqtt in flask application simultaneously over wsgi

Tags: flask, mqtt, wsgi

I created a flask application that consists of MQTT client which simultaneously subscribe data from esp32 and store it in database.

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort,make_response,jsonify, flash, url_for
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json
import config
import db_access

#mqtt code
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    topic = message.topic
    print("line 12 - topic checkpoint - ",topic)
    msgDecode=str(message.payload.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
    msgJson=json.loads(msgDecode) #decode json data
    print("line 15 - json checkpoint - ",type(msgJson))
    # deviceID = msgJson["DeviceID"]
    # currentCounter = msgJson["Counter"]
    # status = msgJson["Status"]    
   db_access.updateStatus(msgJson["DeviceID"],msgJson["Status"])



app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')



'''Web portal routes'''

@app.route('/device/switch', methods=['POST'])
def switch():
    #parameter parsing
    deviceID = request.args.get('deviceID')
    status = request.args.get('status')
    statusMap = {"on":1,"off":0}

    #MQTT publish
    mqtt_msg = json.dumps({"deviceID":int(deviceID),"status":statusMap[status]})
    client.publish(config.MQTT_STATUS_CHANGE_TOPIC,mqtt_msg)

   time_over_flag = 0
    loop_Counter = 0

    while status != db_access.getDeviceStatus(deviceID):
        time.sleep(2)
        loop_Counter+=1
        if loop_Counter ==2:
            time_over_flag = 1
            break

    if time_over_flag:
        return make_response(jsonify({"statusChange":False}))
    else:
        return make_response(jsonify({"statusChange":True}))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db_access.createUserTable()
    db_access.insertUserData()
    db_access.createDeviceTable()
    db_access.insertDeviceData()


    print("creating new instance")
    client = mqtt.Client("server") #create new instance
    client.on_message=on_message #attach function to callback
    print("connecting to broker")
    client.connect(config.MQTT_BROKER_ADDRESS)
    client.loop_start()
    print("Subscribing to topic","esp/#")
    client.subscribe("esp/#")
   app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

This is code in ____init____.py

db_access.py is consist of database operations and config.py consist of configurations. 
Will this work in apache?
also, I have no previous experience with WSGI

Comment: What is the need for flask here?  I think you need to add some background on what you want to acheive.  You've left out the routes, so it's difficult to see how this relates to the `Client.*` functions you've listed. Typically that code in the `if` clause won't be executed when launched with a wsgi server.  Although if it did work with wsgi, it should be fine behind Apache. Definitely need more info here...

Comment: ok... I will update with full code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with launching your code (as included) with a WSGI server, is the part in that last `if` block, only gets run when you execute that file directly with the `python` command.

To make this work, I'd try moving that block of code to the top of your file, around here:

```
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')

db_access.createUserTable()
db_access.insertUserData()
db_access.createDeviceTable()
db_access.insertDeviceData()

print("creating new instance")
client = mqtt.Client("server") #create new instance
client.on_message=on_message #attach function to callback
print("connecting to broker")
client.connect(config.MQTT_BROKER_ADDRESS)
client.loop_start()
print("Subscribing to topic","esp/#")
client.subscribe("esp/#")
```

I'd also rename that `__init__.py` file, to something like `server.py` as the init file isn't meant to be heavy.

Once you've done that, run it with the development server again and test that it works as expected.

Then install a WSGI server like gunicorn into your virtual enviornment:

```
pip install gunicorn
```

And launch the app with gunicorn (this command should work, assuming you renamed your file to `server.py`):

```
gunicorn --bind '0.0.0.0:5000' server:app
```

Then test again.

Comment: I hosted on virtualhost in apache on port 80. But MQTT is not working so can you tell me how to achieve it on apache?

Comment: also, if I rename __init__.py to app.py, what code shall I put in __init__.py. I don't know much about __init__.py . I think it this file run when respective packages is import. Please help... I have no previous experience hosting app with wsgi.